# How to Move Maven Target Archive files into Server Deploy Folder?

Tags: java, maven, deployment, jboss

I have a Maven, Java project with Eclipse and Jboss 4. Currently, after doing clean, install goals I am moving EAR and WAR files into Jboss Deploy folder manually. But every time this process hard to do. Are there any plug-ins or tools to do this job? I tried the "org.codehaus.mojo" plug-in but it did't work. Are there any other goals in Maven to deploy automatically to Server from Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

For such purposes you can use [cargo](http://cargo.codehaus.org/) which is intended for functional tests but supports the deployment of artifacts like ear, war into appropriate container.

Answer (score 0):

may maven-war-plugin can help you

Comment: It would help if you could explain how the maven-war-plugin would help.

Comment: specify the outputDirectory attribute. so, how the maven-war-plugin wouldn't help